# JSF SelectOneMenu Value not passing values to actionbean

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu

I have a set of selectoneMenu list. The behavior of the dropdown is not constant.
Sometimes it passes the value as null, or still holds the existing values.

Anything i missed out? Or need to change any configuration?

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="blSearchzoneInput" value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneId}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneList}" var="c"
         itemValue="#{c.zoneId}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What converter, if any, are you using for this component?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. The cause of the problem is not visible in the code posted so far. Please post the smallest possible but **complete** view and bean code which we can just copy'n'paste'n'run in order to see the problem ourselves. In order to prepare that, you need to create a standalone view and bean for that and test it yourself before copying. Please also mention the JSF impl/version used.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply sorry for the confusion,i found the solution which i had to add two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="blSearchzoneInput" value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneId}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneList}" var="c"
         itemValue="#{c.zoneId}" immediate="true" onchange="javascript: return this.form.submit();" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```